# What's the road to get the convenience of REPL in a unix shell? (or viceversa)

Tags: shell, scripting, read-eval-print-loop

I use a lot of commands providing exposing a sort of API via subcommands. For instance,

```
git push
bzr push
apt-get install
```

After a while, I get tired of writing *git* push, *git* commit, *git* something... because I know the only thing I'm using to 'commit', 'push', etc. is git at this moment.

Having played with languages providing a REPL (Ruby, Python, etc.) I was missing the convenience of typing.

```
$ git pus...           ## arrgh!
$ from git import *
$ push                 ## yes!
```

I see a clear symmetry between commands like git and namespaces or modules in the forementined programming languages.

So, the question is: what does it take to have support for namespaces in SHELL? or vice-versa, What does it take to have these language replace the SHELL?

Comment: Allegedly, some people use perl as an interactive shell.  (I've never met such a person.)

Answer (score 1):

This would be extremely hard to do generically. However, you can approximate something similar...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cmd="${1-echo}"

history -r
while read -p"$cmd\$ " -e -r -a input ; do
    history -s -- "${input[@]}"
    "$cmd" "${input[@]}"
done
```

Invoke with the name of the command, e.g.

```
./wrapper apt-get
```

And now when you say e.g. `install foo` you will actually execute `apt-get install foo`.

Additional improvements, such as more intelligent tab completion, are possible but would certainly require command-specific code.